# How to implement slideToggle functionality after load an external page with load()

Tags: jquery

I want to implement slideToggle functionality after load an external page inside a DIV using load(). The idea is I have three different tabs each upon click will load three different content from three external pages inside that mentioned DIV. When I will click one tab it will load the one external page after that if I click to the same tab it will slide up the content. Next if I click to the second tab it will load its related content with load() and accordingly the first open tab content will be slide up. Please give any suggestion.

Comment: It depends on load time if content is heavier then you won't get anything. bettter would be try something then if you get any issues with the js code then post the question.

Comment: How does your model look? Have you written any code? If so, please post it

Comment: give some code. use jsfiddle

Comment: 17 mins are passed no update in question and response, voting to close.

Comment: jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/gMESa/5/. But here I just put two tabs and two external pages for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following. Just put in your urls you are referencing to in the relevant a tags:

HTML:

```
<div>
  <ul id="tabs">
      <li><a title="type1" href="http://externalurl1">tab1</a></li>
      <li><a title="type2" href="http://externalurl2">tab2</a></li>
      <li><a title="type1" href="http://externalurl3">tab3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>

<div class="content"></div>
```

jQuery

```
$('ul#tabs li a').each(function(){

    $(this).click(function(){

      $('div.area').slideUp(300);
      $('div.area').empty();
      $('div.area').load($(this).attr('href'));
      $('div.area').slideDown(300);
      return false;
    });


});
```

Let me know if it works

UPDATE:

Here is a working solution: http://plnkr.co/edit/DUSrZHJD9H37s6u2aRmN?p=preview